# Get address of member of struct using pyelftools

Tags: python, pyelftools

I am using the pyelftools to read an elf file. How can I get an offset value or address of a member in a struct? For example, say I have the following struct in C.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int valA;
} TsA;

typedef struct
{
    int valB;
} TsB;

typedef struct 
{
    int valC;
    TsB b;
} TsC;

typedef struct
{
    TsA a;
    TsC c;
} TsStruct;

TsStrcut myStruct;
```

How can I get an address of `myStruct.c.b.valB`? I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143326/extract-detailed-symbol-information-struct-members-from-elf-file-compiled-with) but did not find any good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find the DIE for the structure, the one with tag `DW_TAG_structure_type` and `DW_AT_name` equal to structure names.

Enumerate the `DW_TAG_member` subdies under it. While there, look at the `DW_AT_member_location`, it's the offset of the corresponding structure element.

It might help if you take a look at the DIE structure visually first. [DWARF Explorer](https://github.com/sevaa/dwex) might help (disclaimer: I wrote it).