# Generating annotated text description of structs with size/offset of fields for a given architecture during compilation?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, struct, packing

Basically, I would like to obtain the information about packing of structs on a given architecture during the compilation process, formatted as a text file with the struct description (code stripped of original comments), with added comments containing the size and offset of a given field.

Let me give an example - consider the following trivial code, `test_struct.c`:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct {
  uint8_t first;    // this is the first field
  uint16_t second;  // second field
  uint32_t third;   // third field is also important
  uint64_t fourth;  // do not forget fourth field
};
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct_t;

MyStruct_t my_object = {
  .first  = 10,
  .second = 20,
  .third  = 30,
  .fourth = 40,
};

int main(void) {
  printf("Start: %d\n", my_object.first);
  while ( 1 ) {
    ;
  }
}
```

I can compile this for PC (say Linux) with:

```
gcc -Wall -g -o test_struct.exe test_struct.c
```

... and I can compile for ARM with:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --specs=nosys.specs -Wall -g -o test_struct.elf test_struct.c
```

Now, for outputting the struct info, I've found [Extract detailed symbol information (struct members) from elf file compiled with ARM-GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143326/extract-detailed-symbol-information-struct-members-from-elf-file-compiled-with) :

> is pahole what you need? it can dump variable structure with size and offset.

... and indeed, on Linux I can do:

```
$ pahole -C MyStruct test_struct.exe
struct MyStruct {
    uint8_t                    first;                /*     0     1 */

    /* XXX 1 byte hole, try to pack */

    uint16_t                   second;               /*     2     2 */
    uint32_t                   third;                /*     4     4 */
    uint64_t                   fourth;               /*     8     8 */

    /* size: 16, cachelines: 1, members: 4 */
    /* sum members: 15, holes: 1, sum holes: 1 */
    /* last cacheline: 16 bytes */
};
```

... and that is the output that I want - compilable text description of the struct, with the original comments stripped, and comments with size and offset of fields added.

However, that "try to pack" worries me - I would like a description of the struct *exactly as-is* in code; and ultimately, I'd like to compare the default packing of the struct between architectures (in this example, Linux and ARM).

So, I was thinking - since it is generally "the same compiler" (GCC) being used in both cases, would it be possible to instruct the compiler (maybe through a custom script?) to generate such descriptions for selected structs in code? Such that it would be the "same" gcc command in a Cmake/Makefile that executes, regardless of which architecture the code is being built for - and it generates the information for that architecture?

If not, I guess I'd be forced to extract this information in a post-build step; in that case, is `pahole` my only option, or are there other tools that can generate this kind of information? `pahole` on Linux seems able to parse the ARM .elf file (`pahole -C MyStruct test_struct.exe`) - but is does that give accurate architecture-specific information? How do I ensure that I get a description of a struct as-is in memory for a given architecture build, without any attempts for packing by such tools?

( and in either of these cases, are there options to control the text formatting? For instance, I'd rather get an output like this, compared to the above `pahole` example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    uint8_t  first;  // 0 1
    uint16_t second; // 2 2
    uint32_t third;  // 4 4
    uint64_t fourth; // 8 8
};
```

)

Comment: Try stripping comments from the code before building.  This may be a two stsge process using the preprocessor

Comment: pahole uses the debug information, so it shows you the struct *exactly as-is* in code.

Comment: The `X byte hole...` comment is just pointing out internal padding. "try to pack" is intended for you to see where these are (as otherwise finding holes in structures is rather annoying), and `pahole` doesn't try to reorganize structs unless you explicitly ask it to. You could always strip those comments from the output if they bother you.

Comment: Many thanks @ssbsa and Hasturkun - I had completely misunderstood the meaning of the "hole" comment, now I understand what it means - great to have it confirmed that I get the struct layout *as-is*!