# Create a global symbol alias to a global extern struct field in C (gcc, cmake)?

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, alias

Let's say I have an `object.c` file, which defines a global variable `MyObject` of type `struct MyObjectStruct_s` which has a field `char mydata[1024]`. While the `MyObject` will end up as a (debug) in the final ELF/executable file - I cannot find `MyObject.mydata`, and thus its address, in the debug info of the executable file.

So, I thought - could I somehow define an alias in the file where `MyObject` is used (in the below example, the file is `main.c`), which would function as a global variable and end up in the symbol table, but have the same address (and properies) as the field `MyObject.mydata`? Here is an example:

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

project(my_project C CXX ASM)

add_executable(my_project
        object.c
        main.c
        )

add_compile_options(
        -Wall
        )

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES 
    OUTPUT_NAME "my_project"
    SUFFIX ".exe"
    )

# target_link_options(my_project ...)
# target_link_libraries(my_project ...)
```

`object.h`

```c
#pragma once

#include <inttypes.h>

struct MyObjectStruct_s {
  char mydata[1024];
};
typedef struct MyObjectStruct_s MyObjectStruct_t;
extern MyObjectStruct_t MyObject;
```

`object.c`

```c
#include "object.h"

MyObjectStruct_t MyObject = {
  .mydata = "Hello world!",
};
```

`main.c`

```c
#include "object.h"
#include <stdio.h> // printf

// try add alias to extern struct field?
//extern char __attribute__ ((alias ("MyObject.mydata"))) var_alias[512]; 
// cannot: error: 'var_alias' aliased to undefined symbol 'MyObject.mydata'

void main(void) {
  printf("%s\n", MyObject.mydata);
}
```

Build this with:

```
cmake  ./ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "Unix Makefiles"
make
```

As you can see, I've tried to follow the example in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html to have `var_alias` be alias for `MyObject.mydata` - however, I get an error "aliased to undefined symbol".

Also, just to confirm:  can see `MyObject` in the output of `nm` for this executable, but no mention of `mydata` there:

```
$ nm my_project.exe | grep 'MyObject\|mydata'
00000001400096e0 r .rdata$.refptr.MyObject
00000001400096e0 R .refptr.MyObject
0000000140008000 D MyObject
```

So, my question is: how can I instruct the `gcc` build process (via CMake), to build the executable in such a way, so that I get a global symbol `var_alias` to be an alias to the specific struct object field `MyObject.mydata` -- and without changing the `object.{c,h}` files?

Comment: `I cannot find MyObject.mydata` Why would you, there is no such object. Why not just use `char *var_alias = MyObject.mydata`??

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk - I just wanted to emphasize that tools for inspection do not display fields usually, but since I found I can do `objdump -Wi my_project.exe | grep mydata` and get the mydata field listed there (via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143326)

Comment: @KamilCuk - just saw the comment edit now; I'm not using `char *var_alias = MyObject.mydata` because `sizeof(var_alias)` will be the size of pointer, and it will appear as such when I inspect the ELF/executable; besides, when I inspect the ELF/executable, `char *var_alias` will point to its own storage area, not the address of `MyObject.mydata`

Comment: Debug information != symbols. You can see anything in debug information, it's not a symbol. `because sizeof(var_alias) will be the size of pointer` Then add `size_t var_alias_size = sizeof(MyObject.mydata)`. Or do `#define var_alias MyObject.mydata`. I do not understand what exactly do you expect - no, you can't create an alias to a member (or, I do not really see a way to do it, except some really-ish hacking). You can create a pointer. If you want, you can open(argv[0]), read yourself debug information, and access the member then, it's a lot work and I have such horrible code at work.

Comment: The question is really confusing. If you know that information about the field is present in DWARF data, then what exactly are you looking for? Why do you need some sort of extra symbol in addition to DWARF debug info?